# Prevent Site logo to shrink to much on mobile view ( elementor)

Tags: wordpress, elementor

When i pass certain limit of pixels on mobile view, the logo start to shrink to much. How can avoid that?
The site logo is on JPG

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8FDF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPFOu.png)

Trying to change the image with another one